# How to get the url of the location where the web application is running from?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I published an MVC application to

```
\\server\wwwroot\DemoFolder
```

I have an HTTP handler placed under a subdirectory "Handlers" which resides under the root "DemoFolder".

```
//server/wwwroot/DemoFolder/Handlers/DemoHttpHandler.ashx
```

How can I get the handler URL using JavaScript? I need to use the handler URL in a HTTP post request to the server.

When I run the application in my local environment, I can access it as below. But when I publish to the server and run the application from `http://server/DemoFolder`, it can't find the handler. I need to prefix the handler with `http://server/DemoFolder`.

```
url: '/Handlers/DemoHttpHandler.ashx'
```

Comment: Assuming you mean the server-side path, you can't. This is because JS runs on the client, long after the HTML left the server. If you want the URL of the client, then use `window.location`

Comment: Please see my updated post. I am not looking to get the server side path. I need to be able to access the handler resource from client side. Thank you.

Comment: Don't put the initial `/` in the URL.

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue.